# Range Numbers PHP

Tags: php

Hy, I'm trying to print the numbers using php Like this:

```
1=1   5=1   1=1
1=2   5=2   1=2
1=3   5=3   .. etc

2=1   6=1
2=2   6=2
2=3   6=3

3=1   7=1
3=2   7=2
3=3   7=3

4=1   8=1
4=2   8=2
4=3   8=3
```

Thank's.

Comment: I have hours and hours, trying to print the numbers exactly in my question but i can't always print an disordered group of numbers

Answer (score 1):

This code will produce similar output. I'm not sure if the columns are deliberate though. You should try to be clearer in your question.

```
foreach(range(1, 8) as $i) {
    foreach(range(1, 3) as $j) {    
        echo $i . '=' . $j . "\n";
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/MpXpwXbc).

Comment: Your code works, but does not write numbers in columns as OP (seems) is asking.. Anyway, OP question is so unclear that your solutions could be the good one :)

Comment: @Marco: Yeah, I'm not sure if they wanted the columns or not.

Comment: Here's the [same demo](http://codepad.org/8FiB5Sjp) but with columns :)